# Install a Linux distrubution on Apple TV Model A1469

Tags: unix, appletv, jailbreak

So, recently, I found an Apple TV at my house. Since it no longer supports Youtube and I don't really have a use for it, I want to make a little makeshift computer for browsing the web. Problem? Unlike the Apple TV 1, the "geniuses" at Apple decided to REMOVE the USB port off Apple TV. So now we have a micro-usb port, but despite having a MicroUSB-USB adapter, I can't connect it and use it at the same time. Why? Because, yet again, the "Geniuses" at Apple put the micro-usb port RIGHT UNDER THE HDMI!

So, is there any way I can install Linux on this? Or at least have my computer recognize the harddrive inside it so I can see it and access it like a normal HDD?

I don't really have the **money** to buy anything right now (don't ask it's personal), so I am depending on free software and a USB Stick (Sandisk Cruzer Blade 16 GB) I have right now.

Also, I would have to use the remote given with the Apple TV. I would appreciate help given on maybe how to get maybe an on-screen keyboard or anything else (if that is an issue)

Comment: Apple TVs are more akin to iPhones than 'regular' computers. You can jailbreak the early ones, but that does basically turn them into big phones. See https://www.cultofmac.com/384188/9-uses-obsolete-apple-tv/ and https://9to5mac.com/2021/07/07/blackb0x-is-a-new-jailbreak-tool-for-older-apple-tv-models/

Comment: @Tetsujin None of the jailbreaks allow the use of web browsers. Plus, I've read both of the articles you included and I do not have access to a Mac.

Comment: Yeah. I don't think you'll ever be able to turn it into a 'computer'.

Comment: The 3rd gen TV (from 2012) has a 32-bit A5 CPU with 1 core. GPU has 2 cores, and there's 512 Mb of RAM. The storage is 8 Gb. Even if you get some kind of Linux on it, it's going to suck.

Comment: @benwiggy and Tetsujin: Yup, I've realized that now - I'm looking to make my own cloud or something like that with it. Yes, it's 8 GB, but thats enough. If you have more info on that, please let me know. Otherwise, thank you two for your help!

Comment: I have had no problems in connecting both a HDMI cable and a micro-USB cable to that model of AppleTV before. Are you sure all this frustration with "geniuses" is really caused by you using some clunky cables? Have you tried with other cables?